# How to override grails properties via environment variables?

Tags: grails

Grails version: `3.2.4`.

Is there any way to override `grails.*` properties via environment variables? For example:

```
grails war
java -Dgrails.env=myenv build/libs/myapp-0.1.war
```

Without add `-Dgrails.env=myenv`, but use environment variables instead.

And, how to set `server.contextPath` in grails `3.2.4`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a method I use to have custom data in the grails config.  In this case I'm setting a config property(grails.app.root) to hold the default installation location in my app, which in my case varies whether it's installed in the cloud or within a customers office.

First I look if it's passed in via the properties (using -D), second whether it's an environment variable, and thirdly it falls back to the catalina base(as its running within Tomcat)

```
String catalinaBase = System.getProperty('catalina.base')
grails.app.root = System.getProperty("APPROOT") ?: System.env.APPROOT ?: catalinaBase
```